# Loading Pages into Div with Jquery/Ajax (Click function not working)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Trying to get content from other pages to load into specific Div from url on click . But for some reason it will not work. 
The link keeps forwarding to the page instead of opening in the div. On top of that the initial load code works. It loads the initial content. after setting an alarm to notify my when I click the link with the desired content it sends the alert. Then I put return false; at the end and now it doesn't load anything. What am I doing wrong. Im using the code that I used a year ago on here. but now its not working on my new website. Please help me determine how to fix this.

Here is my AJAX code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#main').load('pages/home.php');

    $('ul#navMenu li a').click(function() {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('main').load('pages/' + page + '.php');
        return false;
    }); 

});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<body class="">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="menu-wrap">
            <nav class="menu">
                <div class="link-list">
                    <center>
                    <ul id="navMenu">
                    <li><a href="pages/home.php"><span>HOME</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/artist.php"><span>TALENT</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>SERVICES</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>MUSIC</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>BEATS</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>VIDEOS</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>CONTACT US</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </center>
                </div>

            </nav>
        </div>
        <button class="menu-button" id="open-button"><img src="img/menubutt.png" height="42" width="42"><span>Open Menu</span></button>
        <div class="content-wrap">
            <div id="main">

            </div>
        </div><!-- /content-wrap -->
    </div><!-- /container -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

And, here's the website testing on my server:

https://trillumonopoly.com/testing

Comment: Try to replace `$('ul#navMenu li a').click(function() {` with `$("ul#navMenu").on("click", "li a", function(event) {event.preventDefault();`

Comment: @rulisp this doesnt work it just opens the page in the same window but not in the div

Comment: Try to eliminate your javascript error, from your console it says https://www.trillumonopoly.com/testing/js/bootstrap.min.js isn't found

Comment: I have corrected this and still same result

Comment: @TrillumonopolyInc btw, not sure that this is a reason, but your site also throws error(in console) `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org)`

Comment: @TrillumonopolyInc, from the console I can see that your script is somehow working but the path is not right, when I click on artist it produce this url
`https://www.trillumonopoly.com/testing/pages/pages/artist.php.php`.
remove the extra .php in your url and double check if https://www.trillumonopoly.com/testing/pages/pages/artist.php is valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I found the real reason of your error.

Take a look at your link `<li><a href="pages/home.php"><span>HOME</span></a></li>`
To be more precise, at `home.php`

In your JS you get full link, e.g. `pages/home.php`, then you add to it `.php` one more time, so your final link is `pages/home.php.php`, but not `pages/home.php`

Comment: this work also had to take the pages/ out too and the .php and just included the page name becuase it is specified where to load from(directory) and the extension in the JS... thx

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

`$('main').load('pages/' + page + '.php');`

to

`$('#main').load('pages/' + page + '.php');`

You have forgotten the `#` at start of `main`

Comment: this doesnt work either. and I corrected it. Still No different result

Comment: this doesnt work either. and I corrected it. Still No different result

Comment: The requested url if wrong :p. You are requesting `https://www.trillumonopoly.com/testing/pages/pages/artist.php.php` (two /pages). Change to `$('#main').load(page);` and will probably work :D

Answer (score 0):

Try correcting your url on page variable and also your main typo:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#main').load('pages/home.php');

    $('ul#navMenu li a').click(function() {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');//your href attribute is '#', which doesn't yield a correct path
        $('#main').load('pages/' + page + '.php');//$('#main') instead of $('main'), for id
        return false;
    }); 

});
```

Comment: after correcting this it still gives me same result